# Compiling Qt for Android: 'mingw32-make' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android, c++, windows, qt, build

I'm trying to compile Qt for Android on Windows, following the steps outlined in http://wiki.qt.io/Android.

When I try to configure it:

> configure -xplatform android-g++ -nomake tests -nomake examples -android-ndk c:\android-ndk-r10d -android-sdk c:\adt\sdk -android-ndk-host windows-x64 -android-toolchain-version 4.8 -skip qttranslations -skip qtwebkit -skip qtserialport -skip qtwebkit-examples -no-warnings-are-errors

I get this error:

> 'mingw32-make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I search for make in my NDK folder, and I found only this tool:

> c:\android-ndk-r10d\prebuilt\windows\bin\make.exe

However, it's named `make`, not `mingw-make`. The tutorial says that only the SDK and the NDK are needed, and they don't contain `mingw-make`. Do I need to installed something else?

Answer (score 0):

I found I had mingw32-make in my Qt Creator installation, so I just added it to PATH, and it seems to work:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32\bin
configure configure -xplatform android-g++ -nomake tests -nomake examples -android-ndk c:\android-ndk-r10d -android-sdk c:\adt\sdk -android-ndk-host windows-x64 -android-toolchain-version 4.8 -skip qttranslations -skip qtwebkit -skip qtserialport -skip qtwebkit-examples -no-warnings-are-errors
```