# 'mingw32-make' is not recognized in cmd while integrate Qt 5.2.1 and OpenCV 2.4.9 in Windows 7

Tags: qt, opencv

I am new to Opencv and Qt and was following the following link:
http://www.laganiere.name/opencvCookbook/chap1s1_2.shtml to integrate them together. 
I had setup the path to mingw32-make and even double checked to make sure the directory have the mingw32-make.exe but still, I continue to get the following error:

'mingw32-make' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

when I tried to compile the OpenCV library in cmd.

Does anyone know the solution to this or could recommend other means to compile the OpenCV other than in the cmd? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: did you add the path to your mingw executable to the `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671803/compiling-qt-for-android-mingw32-make-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-ext?rq=1)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, yes I did add the Mingw executable to the PATH environment variable.